# Jqgrid multiselect limit?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, multi-select, jqgrid-php

Is there anyway to set quota to multiselect rows? I mean how i can do :

```
If multiselectedrows count > 5
   alert ("You Can't Select More Than 5 Rows");
```

I'm already checked the manual but there is no option to do this. I'm a newbie on Js/JQuery, so i don't know how to count selected rows.

Comment: I tried that but no luck :S
var count = jQuery('#grid').length;

Answer (score 3):

*Before* the row will be selected the [beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) will be called. You can examine the number of currently selected rows (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202241/jqgrid-multiselect-selected-rows-count/7202776#7202776)) and whether the row which will be selecting  currently are not already in the [selarrrow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) (like `var selRowIds = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow'); if ($.inArray(rowid, selRowIds) < 0)`). In the case you can display a message to the user and then prevent row selection by returning `false` from your [beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) event handler.